# Angular material expansion panel error - TypeError: this.driver.containsElement is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui, angular6, angular-animations

Angular material's expansion panel depends on BrowserAnimationsModule. I have included animation module but when I create a simple expansion panel it crashes with error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.driver.containsElement is not a function
>       at TransitionAnimationEngine.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.TransitionAnimationEngine._balanceNamespaceList
>   (browser.js:2765)
>       at TransitionAnimationEngine.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.TransitionAnimationEngine.createNamespace
>   (browser.js:2743)
>       at TransitionAnimationEngine.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.TransitionAnimationEngine.register
>   (browser.js:2784)
>       at InjectableAnimationEngine.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationEngine.register (browser.js:3815)
>       at AnimationRendererFactory.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.AnimationRendererFactory.createRenderer
>   (animations.js:140)
>       at DebugRendererFactory2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRendererFactory2.createRenderer
>   (core.js:12225)
>       at createComponentView (core.js:11179)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:12204)
>       at Object.debugCreateComponentView [as createComponentView] (core.js:11715)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:11220)

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                This is the expansion title
              </mat-panel-title>
              <mat-panel-description>
                This is a summary of the content
              </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
    <div id="map" style="height: 550px"></div>
</div>
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { CoreModule } from '@app/core';
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { QuoteService } from './quote.service';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    LeafletModule,
    MatExpansionModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    QuoteService
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Note that this is a simple Angular 6 application installed with @angular/material , @angular/cdk and @angular/animations

**Angular and Package Versions:**

> Angular CLI: 6.0.7 Node: 8.9.3 OS: win32 x64 Angular: 6.0.3
>
> @angular-devkit/architect         0.6.7 @angular-devkit/build-angular 
>   0.6.7 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.7 @angular-devkit/core              0.6.7 @angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.7 @angular/animations               6.0.6 @angular/cdk                      6.3.1 @angular/cli                      6.0.7 @angular/material                 6.3.1 @ngtools/webpack                  6.0.7 @schematics/angular               0.6.7 @schematics/update                0.6.7 rxjs                              6.2.0 typescript                        2.7.2 webpack                           4.8.3

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a bug with that version of animations package. Do a temporary fix and rollback to 6.0.5. It will solve your issue as shown on this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-expand-panel)(your version of animations throws the error).

```
npm install --save @angular/animations@6.0.5
```

If this does not fix the issue, do a full update of packages in question:

```
$ ng update @angular/cli
$ ng update @angular/core
$ ng update @angular/material
```

Comment: Just fixed a similar issue with `npm install --save @angular/animations@6.0.5`. Thanks!!

Comment: Fixed my issue too, my @angular/animations was 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

this error comes with latest version of animation module i.e in @angular/animations@6.0.9.
 But if we install @angular/animations@6.0.5, problem will be sort. This issue is solved for paginator as well as mat-sort-header property .